# What is the best way to handle domain exceptions in Tapestry web application?

Tags: java, validation, exception, domain-driven-design, tapestry

I'm having some dilemmas on how to process and handle checked exceptions that are thrown by my domain objects while using Tapestry to create the web GUI as a presentation layer.

Assume I have a domain object, `Foo` that throws `FooException` on one of its methods:

```
public class Foo {
    ...
    public void fooMethod throws FooException() {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Now, assume I have a Tapestry page called `Bar` where `Foo` object is, for example, being edited with `BeanEditor`.

Now, to ensure illegal values are not passed to `BeanEditor` for creating `Foo` object, I can think of two basic ways to do that:

1. Tapestry field validation using `@Validate` annotation

   In this case, if we can filter and check inputs via regexes or by limiting values or doing similar actions made available by `@Validate` we'll get a nifty error message next to the field we're editing and the submit will fail, thus making the user think about what he wrote there and how to fix it.
2. Catching domain exception and doing actions based on it

   I assume this scenario offers more options regarding what can and cannot be done. For example, if the used needs to enter `URL` and makes a mistake while doing so, the `URL` constructor will throw its own `MalformedURLException`. We can catch that exception in our Java code, but my question is, what to do next and how?

Does Tapestry offer any special mechanisms of handing domain exceptions (checked and/or unchecked), other than that exception window that pops up when things break apart?

Are there any patterns on how to solve this particular problem?

Where do you draw the limit between common and ordinary exceptions like `IndexOutOfBoundsException` and some domain-specific ones like `FooException`?

:D

Comment: Not familiar with Tapestry. But this [question and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18168576/should-i-throw-illegalargmentexception-when-user-of-given-id-not-exist/18169076#18169076) may help with your ordinary-domain-spec exceptions one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is applying validations to fields. One way is using @Validate. Another one is to use the Bean Validation (JSR 303) annotations by adding tapestry-beanvalidator, which is explained here: http://tapestry.apache.org/bean-validation.html.

In addition, in Tapestry, all form field component trigger a "validate" event before the value is applied to the property.

http://tapestry.apache.org/forms-and-validation.html explains it all. For example, supposing you have a form field with a t:id of "count", you could validate it by declaring an event handler method:

```
void onValidateFromCount(Integer value) throws ValidationException {
    if (value == 13) throw new ValidationException("Thirteen is an unlucky number.");
}
```

Comment: What about the case where you have a list of values you need to fill and each field may require different validation regex, based on some properties of that current field?

Comment: In this case, it seems to me the best solution would be to create a custom Validator for this specific validation.